# How to ads string match only once in loop in apache POI HSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I have a spreadsheet containging rows much like this

```
SomeText1 SomeText2 SomeText3
Tommy     Tommy      John
Gilaen    Tamara     Shaz
Tamara     Phil      Tamara
```

I want to filter for rows containing 'Tamara' so the rows I should get will be

```
SomeText1 SomeText2 SomeText3
Gilaen    Tamara     Shaz
Tamara     Phil      Tamara
```

To try to do this I am using the following code

```
  Map<String,String> mapEndoscBarr= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
            HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fis);
            HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0);

            List<HSSFRow> filteredRows = new ArrayList<HSSFRow>();

            //Filter by pathology from what I am given
            Iterator<Row> rows= sheet.rowIterator(); 
            while (rows.hasNext ()){
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next ();  
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator (); 
             while (cells.hasNext ()){
                 HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next (); 
                  if (cell.toString().contains("Tamara")) {
                      filteredRows.add(row);
                    }
             }
            }
```

However the loop adds the row everytime the match is found so that I end up with duplicated rows as follows:

```
SomeText1 SomeText2 SomeText3
Gilaen    Tamara     Shaz
Tamara     Phil      Tamara
Tamara     Phil      Tamara
```

How can I force just one match so I don't get this duplicate and it matches if Tamara is present anywhere in the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just break out of the cell iteration once a match is found in any of the cells:

```
Map<String,String> mapEndoscBarr= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
            HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fis);
            HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0);

            List<HSSFRow> filteredRows = new ArrayList<HSSFRow>();

            //Filter by pathology from what I am given
            Iterator<Row> rows= sheet.rowIterator(); 
            while (rows.hasNext ()){
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next ();  
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator (); 
             while (cells.hasNext ()){
                 HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next (); 
                  if (cell.toString().contains("Tamara")) {
                      filteredRows.add(row);
                      break;
                    }
             }
            }
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Thought I was going to have to rearrange the loop.